# вычислить двумерный список согласно формуле и найти произведение его элементов удовлетворяющих неравенству

Tags: python

Для меня это что-то суперсложное, сколько не пытался вникать, так и не смог разобраться что от меня требуется :(, Благодарен за любую помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Многомерный список - просто список из списков. Если для Вас ЭТО - суперсложное, может, программирование просто не Ваше?

Comment: Не моё в данном случае, это алгебра. - Её я никогда не понимал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий вариант

```
import math

a = lambda k,n: n*f(k)+math.sin(k)*g(n)
f = lambda k: 13.4*math.sin(-1.26)*math.cos(abs(k/7.5))
g = lambda n: 2*math.sin(abs(2*n))*math.cos(2*n)-11.6*math.sin(n/0.4-1)

l = [[a(k, n) for k in range(1,5)] for n in range(1,5)]

for n in range(len(l)):
    for k in range(len(l[n])):
        print(l[n][k],end=" ")
    print()

m = 1

for n in range(len(l)):
    for k in range(len(l[n])):
        if l[n][k] > 2 and l[n][k] < 10:
            m *= l[n][k]

print(m)
```

Comment: `3.5 in range(2, 10) --> False`

Comment: Исправил на `l[n][k] > 2 and l[n][k] < 10`

Answer (score 1):

```
def show(a):
    for r in a:
        print ', '.join(['{:6.3f}'.format(i) for i in r])

from math import sin, cos


def f(x):
    return 13.4 * sin(-1.26) * cos(abs(x/7.5))

def g(x):
    return 2 * sin(abs(2*x)) * cos(2*x) - 11.6 * sin(x/0.4 - 1)

def elem(k, n):
    return n * f(k) + sin(k) * g(n)

def matrix(K, N):
    return [[elem(k+1, n+1) for k in range(K)] for n in range(N)]

m = matrix(4, 4)
show(m)
```

Формулы у Вас какие-то бессмысленные...

Произведение:

```
def prod(m, lo, hi):
    p = 1.0
    for r in m:
        for i in r:
            if lo < i < hi:
                p *= i
    return p

print prod(m, 2, 10)
```

Но там нет элементов в этом диапазоне.